# Exporting a simple data object from svelte store with i18n

Tags: javascript, svelte

For my simple website I want to "collect" all configurable text data in one place.

How can I use a custom array with i18n inside a store?

This is the error:

```
'apps' is not exported by src\config\contents.svelte, imported by src\routes\index.svelte
```

contents.svelte

```
<script>

import { readable } from 'svelte/store';
import { _ } from "svelte-i18n";

let myapps = [
     {  
       title: "MyApp",
       subtitle: $_('products.myapp.subtitle'),
       price: "$10"
     },
     { 
       title: "MyApp2",
       subtitle: $_('products.myapp2.subtitle'),
       price: "$15"
     }
];

export const apps = readable(myapps);

</script>
```

index.svelte

```
<script>
import { apps } from "../config/contents.svelte"
</script>

<GridLayout {apps}/>
```

Completely unrelated file:
pricing.svelte

```
<script>
import { apps } from "../config/contents.svelte"
</script>

<PriceLayout {apps}/>
```

I used to define `apps` in `index.svelte` like this:

```
let apps = [];

// Trigger translation when the locale changed.
locale.subscribe((newLocale) => {
    setApps();
});

function setApps(){
    apps = [
     {  
       title: "MyApp",
       subtitle: $_('products.myapp.subtitle'),
       price: "$10"
     },
     { 
       title: "MyApp2",
       subtitle: $_('products.myapp2.subtitle'),
       price: "$15"
     }
   ];
}
```

which worked, but then I couldn't access the price in `pricing.svelte`. So I wanted to use `stores.js` (all the `svelte stores` use `js` extensions) but then the `$_ i18n` was not found. So I made the `stores.js` a `stores.svelte` component, but now I can't use the data externally.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a solution.

The store is a `contents.js` plain js file. No translation functions included. Translatable texts are just strings like `subtitle: 'products.myapp.subtitle'`.
The component that uses this string then wraps it in the translation function `{$_(subtitle)}`.